# Combination of subjunctive mood and adverbial clause

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Is the following sentence correct?

> If I spent all my money on my girlfriend, even though she does get instant gratification, it is not sustainable.

Or, should I say:

> If I spent all my money on my girlfriend, even though she would get instant gratification, it would not be sustainable.

Really confused, please help me.

Comment: If I ***spend***...

Answer (score 1):

The "it is not sustainable" section of the first sentence is in present tense which requires the rest of the sentence to be in a matching tense.

Since you are inquiring about future possibilities that could be the results of some future action (*"If I spent all my money on my girlfriend..."*), the second sentence is better since the word **would** is used when talking about possibility.

The first sentence would work if it was this way:

> I spent all my money on my girlfriend, and even though she gets instant gratification, it is not sustainable.

I recommend reading up on ***Modal Verbs*** becuase **would** and its related words are tricky words to understand, especially if you come from a language where tense doesn't exist.

Comment: I like the part about the matching tense enough to upvote the answer, but I think there's  more going on. The present tense is the only way to keep the conditional from being contrary to fact: *If I spend all my money on my girlfriend, then she gets instant gratification but it is not sustainable*. CCtoF can be expressed by the subjunctive -- *If I were to spend* (present/future time) and *If I had spent* (past time) -- and the consequent clauses would require the modal *would*.

Comment: Originally I was going to do that, but I felt like there are other questions that can better describe it than listing off all these possible uses of 'would' rather than just answering his questions and giving him an avenue to look up modals. Also stating something like "Along with these complicated concepts, it's also a matter of style." I thought would be too confusing.